# Yahoo Finance Unparseable Date

Tags: java, processing, yahoo-finance, control-p5

I am trying to pull stock data from yahoo finance using the yahoo finance api for java. My program was working absolutely fine up until yesterday, when this piece of code just stopped working, throwing up the following errors:

```
SEVERE: Unparseable date: "11/17/2014"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/17/2014"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at yahoofinance.Utils.parseDividendDate(Utils.java:176)
    at yahoofinance.quotes.stock.StockQuotesData.getDividend(StockQuotesData.java:87)
    at yahoofinance.quotes.stock.StockQuotesData.getStock(StockQuotesData.java:105)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:336)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:76)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:61)
    at controlp5userinterface.ControlP5UserInterface.setup(ControlP5UserInterface.java:75)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controlp5userinterface.ControlP5UserInterface.setup(ControlP5UserInterface.java:76)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Here is my code for the section that has stopped working, I can post the complete code if it is of any help. I know that the error is in parsing the date in the yahoo finance cvs file returned but I have no idea why its happening now when it worked perfectly beforehand.

```
Stock[] stocks = new Stock[symbols.length];
    double[] quotePrices = new double[stocks.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<stocks.length; i++){
        String symbol = symbols[i];
        stocks[i] = YahooFinance.get(symbol); //error is here
        quotePrices[i] = stocks[i].getQuote().getPrice().doubleValue();
        System.out.println("Price: " + quotePrices[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Finished finance import");
```

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong dateformat.

Comment: Are you able to influence the data format? Or somehow tell the `YahooFinance` library which locale to use?

Comment: how can I change it? all of the csv file processing is done by the API

Comment: Probably you'll have to raise the defect with the API provider.

Comment: Clearly the CSV is not compatible with the library you're using to parse it, as the `yahoofinance.Utils.parseDividendDate` is failing to parse the date, probably because the date is in U.S. date format (month/day/year) which is essentially unused outside of the U.S., parts of Canada, and (fewer) parts of south America. It would appear `yahoofinance.Utils.parseDividendDate` is expecting something else (top contenders would be year/month/day, year-month-day, day/month/year, and so on, but you'd have to check with them).

Comment: any idea why this is only happening now? This part of my code has worked faultlessly for months now

Comment: You need to show the code of `yahoofinance.Utils.parseDividendDate(Utils.java:176)` - it can't parse the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, probably because you expect a different format...

Comment: Yahoo might have recently changed its internal format, or the settings of your pc might have changed somehow.

Comment: Try updating the library. Looks like the error was fixed in January https://github.com/sstrickx/yahoofinance-api/issues/4

Comment: I have the most up to date library, another case with the same issue was opened yesterday. Ill just have to try find some sort of workaround. Many thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed in v1.2.3 (in the meantime v1.3.0 is available, which is recommended)

Furthermore, if the library is unable to parse the dividend date, it will write an error to the log file (for example: `SEVERE: Unparseable date: "11/17/2014"`), but the exception is caught and the dividend date will just be `null`.

It is possible for Yahoo Finance to not return any dividend date at all, so please check if it's `null` before trying to use it.

In case you encounter a problem like this, please don't hesitate to create an issue through Github.